# I am here trying to work again with os module but it is not working properly it is throwing error, I am making an desktop assistant AI in python

Tags: python, path, artificial-intelligence, desktop-application

So right now i am making an AI assistant like (SIRI) from python so rn i am able to only open websites and able to tell the time now i want to open files and play music in my dekstop and i definetely need OS module for that but whenever i am using it, it displays error like when i am asking it to do anything related to system opening any app that involves OS module it takes the word of the sentence and throws error like---- (EG:- "OPEN DISCORD") so the error it shows is ('open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.)
Here below i am attatchinging the code:-------

```
import win32com.client as wincom
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import os
import openai
import datetime

speak = wincom.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

def say(text):
    print(f"{text}")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with  sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5            #BY DEFAULT IT IS 0.8 SEC
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="eng-in")
            print(f"User said: {query}")
            return query
        except Exception as e:
            print("Jarvis couldn't hear,please try again speaking")
            speak.Speak("Jarvis couldn't hear,please try again speaking")
            return "Jarvis couldn't hear,please try again speaking"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('PyCharm')
    speak.Speak("Hello I am Jarvis AI,how may I help you")
    while True:
        print("Listening.....")
        query = takeCommand()
        sites = [["youtube","https://www.youtube.com"], ["wikipedia", 
"https://www.wikipedia.com"],
        ["google","https://ww.google.com"],]
        for site in sites:
            if f"Open {site[0]}".lower() in query.lower():
                speak.Speak(f"Opening {site[0]} Sir....")
                webbrowser.open(site[1])
            if "the time" in query:
                hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")
                min = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M")
                speak.Speak(f"Sir  time is{hour} hour {min} minutes")
            if "open discord".lower() in query.lower():
                os.startfile(f"open C:\\Users\\MANAN\\Desktop\\Discord") #HERE IT IS THROWING ERROR
```

I wanted to open discord or any other app in the PC but this OS module issue is not getting resolved

Comment: I think all you need is `os.startfile(r"C:\Users\MANAN\Desktop\Discord")`. No need to use the `f` (format) specifier, as you're not formatting anything. Instead, use the `r` (raw) string literal so you don't need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Bro but that is the issue whenever I use an OS command it is throwing an error as i told you above

Comment: And another thing i am using f string so that in future i want to open anything in my desktop so i will just puta dictionary bracket and just ask user to open and say the name so that it puts the same name in the  file path and open the app the reason i am using f string but that's not the main issue bro OS thingy is not working